# MissingManifestResourceException on one server, not on others

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I've been pulling my hair out over this one.

Our staging server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard) has recently stopped cooperating. To be more specific, when our ASP.NET MVC 3 site is started, it gives the exception

> MissingManifestResourceException: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Resources.TranslatedUrl.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "App_GlobalResources" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.

which means the site goes through startup, but then encounters an error when trying to register our (customized) translatable routes using GlobalResources. The same code base works flawlessly on our demo server, virtual machine server and Visual Studio's development server. I even did a revert of the code base to a point in time where the site was demonstrably working, but no luck. This leads me to believe the problem is with the server itself, or IIS 7, in which the site runs.

Problem is, no one has (to my knowledge) done any reconfigurations of IIS or the server. I've been moving our CI from CruiseControl.net to TeamCity, but the compile and setup is done on a separate server, which, once all compilation and configuration is complete, moves the files to the staging server using Web Deploy. Is it possible that Web Deploy could, in some way, have altered the config of IIS or the server?

I suppose it is also possible that our hosting provider could have made some changes I don't know about, but it seems unlikely.

Any ideas? I'm all out of them myself.